# How can I replace a full image placeholder by an empty one?

Tags: automation, powerpoint, python-pptx

I would like to programatically delete image placeholders which are full (`PlaceholderPicture` objects in the `python-pptx` API)
and replace them with empty ones (`PicturePlaceholder`), the goal being to "refresh" pictures instead of always having to fill out an empty presentation.

I think I know how to delete a shape, but creating a new PicturePlaceholder proves harder than expected.

When I try to create one I am asked to provide a `sp` and a `parent` and I cannot find in the documentation what these parameters refer to.

Does my approach make sense, and if so is it possible to create new placeholders programmatically? Could anyone explain what are the parameters I should pass to the constructor?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried simply deleting the shape? When you do that to normal shapes, they're gone. When you delete a placeholder that's holding content, it deletes the content and leaves a blank placeholder.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; I can't find anything in the docs to delete shapes unfortunately. Would you mind giving me resources for that if you have them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python-pptx` has no API support for this, which means you would need to directly manipulate the underlying XML of the slide to accomplish it (and be outside the `python-pptx` "safety net").

`sp` is the shape element (generally an `<p:sp>` element, hence the name) and `parent` would be a reference to the slide.

As a general approach, I would create an empty placeholder and compare its XML to that of a "filled" placeholder which is the same in every respect. Then the job is to make one into the other.

Note that a picture placeholder has a relationship to the "image part" (e.g. PNG file) stored elsewhere in the PPTX package (.pptx file). This will need to be dealt with and not left dangling.

Another possibility is just to swap the image and leave everything else in place, which on paper at least would be less disruptive.

Because none of these options has API support, pursuing them involves taking on responsibility for a lot of details that `python-pptx` takes care of for you and learning a fair amount about the internals. If that sounds like something you'd rather avoid then you'll want to find another way to accomplish the broader outcome you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, but I'm afraid there's something I'm not getting. I'll cite the `Understanding placeholders` section of the docs:
`A rich-content placeholder enters populated mode when content such as a picture is inserted and returns to unpopulated mode when that content is deleted.`

Yet the `Working with placeholders` section doesn't mention how to unpopulate such a placeholder. I understand that it's not that simple because the XML element itself has to be replaced by a different one, but I just want to be sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: If you open the presentation in PowerPoint and delete the placeholder content, it goes back to being an empty placeholder of the original type. There is no support for this "delete-placeholder-content" in the current version of `python-pptx`, so this only happens if you delete the content "manually".

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. I'm guessing, since PowerPoint can do it on just pressing Backspace, replicating this could be done through `python-pptx`? I'll try to look into it when I have time.

Comment: @augustebaum No need to replicate Backspace. If the current shape is a filled placeholder and you delete it, you're left with an empty placeholder. Note: NOT the same placeholder as before ... it'll have a new name and ShapeID.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks but I don't understand how to do this from the docs, and also scanny just said that the API doesn't support this. If you know how to do this I'd be delighted, though!

Comment: If you delete the "filled-placeholder" shape in `python-docx`, that shape is just gone. It doesn't turn into anything. I suspect @SteveRindsberg is thinking about deleting that placeholder shape using VBA or win32com or whatever from Python.

Comment: @scanny Correct ... what I described was how it works in VBA or manually via the UI. Granted, it's sort of an odd/confusing behavior.

Comment: I was thinking I could create an empty placeholder with the same characteristics as the shape I'm deleting. I can get the dimensions of the shape but I'm not sure about the rest. How would I go about doing this? I would create another thread for this, but it turns out _this_ is what I wanted to know in the first place.

Comment: That's a pretty big job @augustebaum. There's no API support for it so you'd have to dive into the XML and manipulate that directly. It's definitely not a short answer.